# Can I apply for a spouse visa for my husband when I am his second wife?

Tags: visa, australia

I am a citizen of Pakistan and currently hold an Australian Student Visa subclass 500. I want to apply for a spouse or sponsorship visa for my husband.
We both applied for a student visa but unfortunately his visa application was refused. Before leaving Pakistan I registered our marriage in Pakistan.
I am the second wife of my husband and in Pakistan it is legal to have more than one wife for a man.
I need your kind assistance regarding visa application, and let me know if I can apply or sponsor a Spouse visa for my husband?

Comment: This has been asked and answered already: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105669/can-having-a-second-wife-affect-my-australian-visa-processing-stay

Comment: That's not a duplicate. That is someone asking if having two wives will invalidate a visa they would otherwise be eligible for. This is about whether someone with a valid student visa can bring their multiply-married husband with them.

Answer (score 9):

**Your marriage will not be recognized in Australia.**

This page on the [recognition of foreign marriages in Australia](https://www.ag.gov.au/families-and-marriage/marriage/get-married)  says:

> An overseas marriage is generally recognised in Australia if it
>
> - was a valid marriage in the overseas country, and
> - would have been a valid marriage here

Your marriage would not be valid in Australia because your husband was already married.

It's not out of the question that there is a loophole  I am unaware of. You should consult a lawyer if you want to try to find one.